# Upload big (2Gb+) files by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rest-client

I have big files on my server and need to send them to another server by http(s).
I use [rest-client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)
It works perfectly with small files, but 2+Gb files cause error.

When I tried with https, I got this error

```
RangeError: integer 2325958991 too big to convert to `int'
```

Tested with local http and got this error

```
2.3.3 :001 > RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4567/upload',  :my_file => File.open("test_file2G", 'rb')                                                                                                                                  
Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:211:in `write'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:211:in `write0'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:185:in `block in write'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:202:in `writing'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:184:in `write'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:188:in `send_request_with_body'
        from /home/rubydev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:121:in `exec'
```

For tests I use sinatra server, it succesfully receives big files for examlpe form curl.

UPDATE
Streamed upload causes same error

Comment: Have you tried streaming? https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#streaming-request-payload

Comment: look into direct upload to cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Gem [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) succesfully sends large files